# How to replace missing items in a dataset?

Tags: replacement, dataset

I am reading Covid data from an external database like so:

```
usDailyTracking = 
  Import["https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/daily.json", 
     "RawJSON"] /. Null -> Missing[] // Dataset;
```

Those data have the problem that, when one of the entries is zero (number of positives, or number of deaths, etc.) then the corresponding entry is simply left out rather than listed as "0". So, now I would like to create a dataset that extracts certain subsets of items while replacing missing entries with zeroes. What I have is this:

```
Clear[toDate];
toDate[num_Integer] := 
 DateObject@{Quotient[num, 10000],
   Quotient[num - Quotient[num, 10000] 10000, 100], Mod[num, 100]}
usDaily = 
  usDailyTracking[
   Table[i, {i, 1, 10}], <|"date" -> toDate[#"date"], 
     "State" -> #"state", "positive" -> #"positive", 
     "negative" -> #"negative", "posNeg" -> #"posNeg", 
     "death" -> #"death"|> &, 
   FailureAction -> {"Replace", <|"date" -> toDate[#"date"], 
       "State" -> #"state", "positive" -> #"positive", 
       "negative" -> #"negative", "posNeg" -> #"posNeg", 
       "death" -> 0|> &}];
```

So the idea would be that, whenever there's a record that does not have an item for "death", a zero is inserted for the missing item. However, with the code above I get this:

```
date    State   positive    negative    posNeg  death 
Thu 23 Apr 2020 AK  337 11824   12161   9
Thu 23 Apr 2020 AL  5778    46863   52641   197
Thu 23 Apr 2020 AR  2465    29125   31590   45
toDate[#date]   #state  #positive   #negative   #posNeg 0
Thu 23 Apr 2020 AZ  5769    52928   58697   249
Thu 23 Apr 2020 CA  37369   444728  482097  1469
Thu 23 Apr 2020 CO  10878   39767   50645   508
Thu 23 Apr 2020 CT  23100   48397   71497   1639
Thu 23 Apr 2020 DC  3361    12569   15930   139
Thu 23 Apr 2020 DE  3308    13604   16912   92
```

Clearly, what I would want is leave the existing items in place, and only replace the missing "death" item, so the above doesn't quite do the job.

Can someone help me fix this?

As a follow-up question, using the `FailureAction` approach, all I can do is detect that "something is wrong", and if so take one specific action. In a more general case, I would want to figure out which one of the items causes the failure, and then replace only the missing item with a zero. What would be the path to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If its only the death column you want replace with 0, you can use ReplaceAll[]

```
test = ReplaceAll[usDailyTracking[[14]], {Missing[] -> 0}]
```

This can also be done for all values of the data

```
test1= ReplaceAll[usDailyTracking, {Missing[] -> 0}]
```